# Understanding excel formula

Tags: excel

I have a excel formual. **=IF(SUMIFS(G:G,D:D,D2)>0,"YES","NO")**

I searched on net but found any suitable answer to understand this.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx

http://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-2007-sumif-and-sumifs-formulas-explained

I did not find any help from the above link. Could any one please help what this formula actully mean?

Comment: Please show what is in D2 as it is important for explaining this formula.

Comment: I think this question should be closed as "Too broad", see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions. You could ask about documentation for the `SUMIFS` function on its own, I guess.

Comment: In my case D2 is : A01444

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to understand how the `SUMIFS(G:G,D:D,D2)` works. It returns the sum of rows within `G:G` where the corresponding `D:D` is equal to `D2`, as explained by the Microsoft link you have already. E.g.

```
  | D    G
--+-----------
1 | H1   H2
2 | A    1
3 | B    2
4 | C    3
5 | D    4
6 | A    5
7 | B    6
8 | C    7
9 | D    8
```

Here, D2 is A. `SUMIFS(G:G,D:D,D2)` will return the sum of values from G where the ones in D are equal to A, which is 1 + 5 = 6

So, if this sum is above `0` in

```
=IF(SUMIFS(G:G,D:D,D2)>0,"YES","NO")
```

Then, put `YES`, otherwise `NO`.

Answer (score 1):

The `SUMIFS` function takes at least three arguments:

- the range to be summed
- the range to be tested
- the condition that the second range is tested for (e.g. ">0")

In your example this function is evaluated; if the result is greater than zero, the outermost `IF` returns the string "YES", otherwise it returns "NO".

In other words - your expressions tells us whether (the sum of all elements in the first range for which the second range meets the condition in the third range), is greater than zero or not.